# Spring MVC + Thymeleaf update options without submitting the form

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm building an HTML `form` that contains 2 `select` element `option` lists. The contents of the second list depend upon the value chosen from the first: the values are loaded from a database when the `option` checkbox is selected.

So I created an `Employee` model object:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data // for getters and setters
public class EmployeeModel {
    List<Department> departments = List.of(Department.values());
    Department department; // selected department
    Set<Employee> employees = new TreeSet<>();
    Employee employee; // selected employee
}
```

Defined the corresponding `form` markup in `EmployeeForm.html`:

```
//html meta and other stuff...
<form th:action="@{/employee/create}" th:object="${employeeModel}" method="post">
    <label for="department">Department</label>
        <select id="department" name="department" th:field="*{department}">
            <option
                    th:each="department: *{departments}"
                    th:value="${department}"
                    th:text="${department.getName()}"></option>
        </select><br>

        <label for="employee">Employee</label>
        <select id="employee" name="employee" th:field="*{employee}">
            <option
                    th:each="employee: *{employees}"
                    th:value="${employee}"
                    th:text="${employee.getFullName()}"></option>
        </select><br>
   </form>
```

Implemented a `Controller` with the following 2 methods:

```
@GetMapping()
public ModelAndView showPage() {
    // VIEW_URL is "EmployeeForm" to point to the view template
    return new ModelAndView(VIEW_URL, Map.of("employeeModel", new EmployeeModel()));
}

@PostMapping(value = "create")
public ModelAndView createEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employeeModel") EmployeeModel model) {
    // extract data and save employee to database...
}
```

And the `Controller` holds a reference to `EmployeeService`, which provides the method:

```
    getEmployeeByDepartment(Department department)
```

that is used to update the `select` element `option` values.

But now I am stuck on updating the `model` and repopulating the `form` because I'm not sure how to trigger the necessary update on the `"departments"` `select` element.

My first idea would be to use `jQuery` to define an `onChange` event listener callback for the value of the checkbox. Is there some other way to handle this in `Spring`?

Technologies in use:

- Java version `"10.0.1" 2018-04-17`
- `spring-boot-starter-web`
- `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf`
- `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`

If further information is required, please feel free to ask-

Answer (score 0):

The best and the clean way to do it is to make an AJAX call to load `employee` options when a `department` is selected (`onChange` event). I believe you are already using jQuery. So, AJAX using jQuery is easy.

This link should give you a head up: http://www.rockhoppertech.com/blog/spring-mvc-3-cascading-selects-using-jquery/

I am not sure which version of jQuery you are using but this link will give you a fair understanding on how to do it.

Comment: ok this was what I had in mind too. Just asked this question to check if there is a way to do this directly using spring without using JavaScript. But thanks think I am going to use jQuery for this task now.